# What does the plus (+) sign mean in the name attribute of the logger element in log4net?

Tags: logging, log4net

What does the plus (+) sign mean in the name attribute of the logger element in log4net?

For example:

```
<logger name="MyProject.MyDataModel.MyClass+Dalc">
    <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
```

In this example, the actual class name is `MyClassDalc` and it is being logged just fine.

Google is being a big meanie when it comes to searching for what symbols mean and searching any of the top results related to the log4net name attribute shows 0 hits for either '+' or 'plus'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the CLR classname for a nested class.

Comment: Not actually related to log4net at all which is why I wasn't finding anything.  Welp that explains that one.  Thanks.